Application upgrade from Xamarin to MAUI is resulting in a NuGet restore loop error
I started an internship this week and have just received my first piece of work - upgrading a super old legacy Xamarin app to MAUI. I have never worked with dotnet or c sharp before so I am just going off documentation I can find online and other guides.
The original project has three sections - a core API, and then the iOS and Android applications. I went to upgrade the API first to .NET 8 as it currently targets netstandard2.0. The app is super old and there is no one here who has used it before or worked on it so when I am stuck like now there's no one to ask or go to for help.
Anyway, I upgraded the tool and it all went well with no errors. However, now I try to build it I get these two errors which I can't get past and don't understand.
The first is related to upgrading packages the project uses. For some reason, it didn't bring in packages the project relies on like Newtonsoft.Json. When I try to add this via the package manager on NuGet, it returns the following error:
Restoring packages for C:\Developer\*\*\*\*.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.forms/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.forms/index.json 205ms
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/vulnerabilities/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-vulnerabilities/2024.10.10.23.29.13/vulnerability.base.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-vulnerabilities/2024.10.10.23.29.13/2024.10.11.11.29.14/vulnerability.update.json
NU1603: CardsView 2.4.8 depends on Xamarin.Forms (>= 3.0.0) but Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.446417 was resolved.
NU1107: Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1 directly to project VanMonster.AppraisalCore to resolve this issue. 
 *.* -> Plugin.Permissions 5.0.0-beta -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 28.0.0.1) 
 *.*-> CardsView 2.4.8 -> Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.446417 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2).
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for '*.*'.

When I try to delete a package, its the same thing:
Restoring packages for C:\Developer\*\*\*\*.csproj...
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/vulnerabilities/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-vulnerabilities/2024.10.10.23.29.13/vulnerability.base.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-vulnerabilities/2024.10.10.23.29.13/2024.10.11.11.29.14/vulnerability.update.json
NU1107: Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1 directly to project VanMonster.AppraisalCore to resolve this issue. 
 VanMonster.AppraisalCore -> Plugin.Permissions 5.0.0-beta -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 28.0.0.1) 
 VanMonster.AppraisalCore -> Rg.Plugins.Popup 1.2.0.223 -> Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2).
Generating MSBuild file C:\Developer\*\*\*\*.csproj.nuget.g.props.
Generating MSBuild file C:\Developer\*\*\*\obj\*.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
Writing assets file to disk. Path: C:\Developer\*\*\*\obj\project.assets.json
Executing nuget actions took 113 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.5898366
========== Finished ==========

Failed to restore C:\*\*\*\*.csproj (in 2.77 sec).
NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.7920800

So I thought ok, I'll install that package Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1 but that asks me to install another package called Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils
I have no idea how to solve this and get past it to the point I can start testing the API. Any ideas on how to proceed would be appreciated.

In the process of upgrading, due to the interdependency of some packages, it is particularly easy to have problems in your question stem during the upgrade process.
For users who need to upgrade Xamarin App to MAUI App, Microsoft has some tutorials,for this ,you can first check the following official documents:
Manually upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to a single project .NET MAUI app,
Upgrade manually to a multi-project app and
Upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to a .NET MAUI app with the .NET Upgrade Assistant.
